# ListView .putExtra from DB Column

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-intent

I am trying to get data from a db column that contains an URL link; The column name is 'goto' w/in the db. I need to pass this into my onItemClick Intent in my ListView to load a webpage into the new/next Activity.

I don't know how to get this to function.  If you can please show code modifications with an explanation, this would be very helpful to me learning. Thnx!

REVISED:

I am now getting data passed but my method is returning the wrong row ID.  I revised the below Activity.  Any help Plz.  THNX

Within my Activities .onCreate (REVISED):

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        // @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) 
        {
            Object o = lv.getSelectedItem();
            //Adapter_AC fullObject = (Adapter_AC)o;

            String url = "gotoURL";
            if(v != null) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)lv.findViewById(R.id.dummy);
                url = (String) tv.getTag();
            }

            Toast.makeText(List_AC.this, "Clicked: " +  url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(List_AC.this, DocView.class);

            i.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

My Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_AC extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Cursor dataCursor;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public Adapter_AC(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
    this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int label_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("label");
    String label = dataCursor.getString(label_index);

    int title_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
    String title = dataCursor.getString(title_index);

    int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("description");
    String description = dataCursor.getString(description_index);

    int goto_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("goto");
    String gotoURL = dataCursor.getString(goto_index);

    holder.text1.setText(label);
    holder.text2.setText(title);
    holder.text3.setText(description);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
}
}
```

Comment: @anticafe  any ideas to what I have wrong?  Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setTag:
At first, we set tag:

```
...
holder.text3.setText(description);
holder.text3.setTag(gotoURL);
```

And when perform onClick event, get tag:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) 
{
    ...
    String url = "";
    if(v != null) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        url = (String) tv.getTag();
    }
    i.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thnx that was very helpful.  The only issue I have now that its pulling data from the wrong DB row. No matter which listItem is selected, it returns the correct column from the same row.  I am sure I am missing something.  Any help would be appreciated. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

In `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` method, there is an `id` arguments, while you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, the id, which is `_ID` column in sqlite database, of selected item will be passed to the `id` argument, so you can get the selected column from DB with this `id` value.

Following is the sample code, hope it can help.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c = queryById(id);
    // Get the url from DB.
    String url = c.getString("url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're pulling data from the wrong row is because you're handling the `convertView` parameter incorrectly. You're only ever setting the `holder` to point at the very first set of `TextView` objects you set up. I think that your `holder` concept is unnecessary. Lose that, set text fields explicitly each time, use the `Cursor` as I mentioned in your previous question.