# ListView clickEvent Selects Wrong DB Row ID - Help!

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView that populates data from a DB into a complex-ListView.  A string in the 'gotoURL' column of the db is a URL to load a link into a WebView using the putExtra intent. When I click on a ListItem to go to the next Activity, my method grabs the correct string data, but it pulls the string from the wrong db row.  As per my 'log.i(...);' indicates in the DDMS, the correct id row is selected but the string from the column is  pulled from the first row id and not from the row id selected(???) - it does this on any ListItem selected.

I cant figure out how to write this to function correctly.  Plz help with example code.  Thank-you.

My Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view2);

    activityTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleBarTitle);
    activityTitle.setText("ADVISORY CIRCULATORS");

    displayResultList();

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setClickable(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            String url = "";
            lv.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);
            TextView tv = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.dummy);
            url = (String) tv.getTag();

            LLog.i("tag", "ID:" + id + "URL: " + url + " selected");
            Intent i = new Intent(List_AC.this, DocView.class);
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void displayResultList() {

    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();

        File dbfile = new File(extStorageDirectory
                + "/Aero-Technologies/flyDroid/dB/flyDroid.db");

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile,
                null);

        Cursor databaseCursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM AC_list ORDER BY `label` ASC", null);

        Adapter_AC databaseListAdapter = new Adapter_AC(this,
                R.layout.list_item, databaseCursor, new String[] { "label",
                        "title", "description", "gotoURL" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.label, R.id.listTitle, R.id.caption,
                        R.id.dummy });

        databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.setListAdapter(databaseListAdapter);

        } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {
            Log.i("tag", "SDCard is NOT writable/mounted");
            Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_AC extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


static Cursor dataCursor;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public Adapter_AC(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
    this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

        holder.text4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int label_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("label");
    String label = dataCursor.getString(label_index);

    int title_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
    String title = dataCursor.getString(title_index);

    int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("description");
    String description = dataCursor.getString(description_index);

    int goto_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("gotoURL");
    String gotoURL = dataCursor.getString(goto_index);

    holder.text1.setText(label);
    holder.text2.setText(title);
    holder.text3.setText(description);
    //holder.text4.setText(gotoURL);
    holder.text4.setTag(gotoURL);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question three different ways? I already answered why you're getting the wrong row in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838765/listview-putextra-from-db-column/5874043#5874043).

Comment: @ColdForged  I have tried your implementation but I get nothing returned (log cat shows null).  Yes the question is similar but the code has changed.  At least now with what I have, a string is returning.  Also, I resubmit because the thread doesn't get pushed to the top of the 'un-answered' Que when a comment or edit has been done (bad design on OS's part - it sits in the same spot/order).

Comment: So the posts go stagnant after a few hrs and no more hits on the counter.  I thank you for your help and I am still continuing to find a work-a-round with your method (it seems more logical).  Being that I was forced onto a steep learning curve (new to Java & Android) to develop this project and there are no "real" resources other than OS, I have to re-submit my q's when I make changes that are closer.  Thnx again and if you are willing to step me farther with your answer, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK your onItemClick has a few things wrong (see inline comments):

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            String url = "";
            lv.getItemIdAtPosition(pos); //you're never storing this value, but that's not the problem


            //This "lv" is the main problem: you're asking the LISTVIEW for the TextView
            //That's why you always get the first one. You should be asking the current view (v) instead
            TextView tv = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.dummy); 
            url = (String) tv.getTag();

            LLog.i("tag", "ID:" + id + "URL: " + url + " selected");
            Intent i = new Intent(List_AC.this, DocView.class);
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

However, why are you trying to use the data in the holder instead of getting the backing tiem?

Comment: Thnx!! @dmon That was it.  Due to my lake of knowledge of Java & Android, this what the only way that would return data of any kind (at least something).  If you have a better method, plz post it as another answer & look closely to the rest of my activity & adapter code.  I think @ColdForged has the right idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862195/how-to-pass-a-string-into-onitemclick-listview/5862821#5862821) but it would return my data as null.  Thnx again.