# Click listView Item Error @ ID #0x5?

Tags: android, listview, webview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I get an error 'Resources Not Found Exception: String resource ID #0x5.  I know it has to do with the i.putExtra(...).  I am trying to pull a string from a DB column 'gotoURL' to pass a URL string from a listItem in my ListView to a WebView Activity.  Any help PLZ!  Thnx!

Im my Activity:

```
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        // @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) 
        {
            Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(List_AC.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(List_AC.this, DocView.class);
            Cursor cursor = Adapter_AC.dataCursor;
            i.putExtra("url", getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gotoURL")));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

The Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_AC extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


static Cursor dataCursor;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public Adapter_AC(Context context, int layout, Cursor dataCursor,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, dataCursor, from, to);
    this.dataCursor = dataCursor;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

        holder.text4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int label_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("label");
    String label = dataCursor.getString(label_index);

    int title_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
    String title = dataCursor.getString(title_index);

    int description_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("description");
    String description = dataCursor.getString(description_index);

    int goto_index = dataCursor.getColumnIndex("gotoURL");
    String gotoURL = dataCursor.getString(goto_index);

    holder.text1.setText(label);
    holder.text2.setText(title);
    holder.text3.setText(description);
    holder.text4.setText(gotoURL);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    protected static final String KEY_TITLE = "text4";
}

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in the onItemClickListner:

> i.putExtra("url", getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gotoURL")));

You ask for the columnindex (an integer), use it as input to the Context.getString() that expects this to be an (existing) Resource ID. From your error I can guess that the columnIndex for "gotoURL" is 5 and no such resource id exists...

I guess what you really want to put in the intent is the string value for the column "gotoURL" as you do it in the adapter?

Comment: & @dmon  Thnx, this is true and I ended up changing everything all together.  Please take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5838765/600984).  Thnx again.